# Ordenar Tabla Horizontalmente Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT asunto, MONTH(created_at) as mes, COUNT(turno) as numero
FROM tikets
where id_sucursal = 1 and subasunto = 'Pago' GROUP BY asunto, mes ORDER BY mes ASC
```

La cual me arroja los resultados así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me preguntaba como podría hacer la consulta para que me saliera así o que tendría que hacer. Gracias por su atención

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

*Aclaro que no tengo datos para confirmar el resultado.*

```
SELECT asunto, 
    COUNT(case when MONTH(created_at) = 2 then turno else 0 END) as FEB,
    COUNT(case when MONTH(created_at) = 3 then turno else 0 END) as MAR,
    COUNT(case when MONTH(created_at) = 4 then turno else 0 END) as ABR
FROM tikets
    where id_sucursal = 1 and subasunto = 'Pago' 
    GROUP BY asunto, mes 
    ORDER BY mes ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema no es de la consulta SQL, sino de como muestras los datos, es decir, que la consulta SQL sería la misma para ambas vistas y por ende, también los datos obtenidos. Simplemente tienes dos vistas diferentes (sólo varia la construcción del HTML y los estilos aplicados).

Answer (score 0):

Existe algo que se llava pivot_table, no estoy seguro de si mySql lo tiene , pero te permite ya ordenar la tabla directamente en la consulta y no desde html o alguna programacion.

Te dejo estos dos tutoriales para mySQL toca mas o menos armar desde sql :

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table
http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/

Espero te sirvan de guia